# How to use window.open function on IBM Worklight?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, business-process-management

Im using this code to show another page on my app

```
var myURLS =JSON.stringify(result.invocationResult.data);
window.open(myURLS , '_blank');
```

the URL on myURLS is:

```
https://ectest556ws1:9444/teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=108351&zResetContext=true
```

but my app redirects to

```
http://10.0.176.232:10080/BPMtest/apps/services/preview/test/common/0/default/%22https://ectest556ws1:9444/teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=108351&zResetContext=true%22
```

and it shows

```
Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error notificado: 404
```

on my mobile in app browser

Comment: Can you able to access the same URL from your mobile default browser? I didn't find any problem with your code. For me it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result.invocationResult.data in your case is already a string. When you run it through JSON.stringify(), it will add quotes around it. This is causing the string to be encoded as a relative URL instead of being used as an absolute URL

Instead, try:

```
window.open(result.invocationResult.data , '_blank');
```

Refer to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for documentation on JSON.stringify